# Which type to declare to avoid copy and make sure returned value is moved

Tags: c++11, reference, return, local, rvalue-reference

Suppose that

- I have a function `A f()`;
- I want to initialize a local variable `a` to the return value of `f`;
- I don't want to rely on RVO;

What is the best option (and why) to avoid the return value of `f` being copied when

1. `a` may have to be modified
2. I know that `a` will not be modified

Options:

a) `A a = f();`
 b) `A&& a = f();`
 c) `const A& = f();`
 d) `const A&& = f();`

---

EDIT:

I would say:

1. b)
2. c)

Because both use references and avoid an extra copy (which could be avoided by RVO as well, but that is not guaranteed). So how come I see option a) suggested most of the time?

I guess the heart of the question is: I get that a) most likely has the same effect as c), so why not use c) instead of a), to make things explicit and independent on the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how come I see option a) suggested most of the time?

Because all 4 options return the value the exact same way. The only thing that changes is the way you bind a variable to the returned temporary.

- a) Declares a variable `a` of type `A` and move-initializes it from the temporary. This is not an assignment, this is initialization. The move constructor will be elided by any popular compiler, provided that you don't explicitly disallow it, which means that the program will just ensure that the storage reserved for the return value is the storage for the `a` variable.
- c) Declares a variable `a` which is a const-reference to the temporary, extending the lifetime of the temporary. Which means that the temporary return value gets storage, and the variable `a` will refer to it. The compiler, knowing statically that the reference points to the returned value, will effectively generate the same code as a).
- b) and d), I am not really sure what they're good for. (and even if that works) I would not take an rvalue reference at this point. If I need one, I would explicitly `std::move` the variable later.

Now :

> a may have to be modified

If `a` may be modified, use :

```
auto a = f();
```

> I know that a will not be modified

If you know that `a` will not be modified, use :

```
const auto a = f();
```

The use of `auto` will prevent any type mismatch. (and as such, any implicit conversion to `A` if `f` happens not to return type `A` after all. Oh, those maintainers...)

Comment: d) is valid but in practice it's the same as c) (and therefore not very useful). b) is similar but the value may be changed. I see no reason why it would be wrong: the result of "f()" is an rvalue and I am just referencing it. Also, the bit I am missing is: if a) has the same effect as c), why not use c) instead of a), to make things explicit and not dependent on the compiler?

Comment: a) creates a local variable for sure. If your f() function starts returning a reference for some reason, c) will bind `a` to an object that is possibly not owned by your function. (and your calling function might start having side-effects) If you want a local variable, declare it as such. If you want a reference, declare a reference.

Comment: If a `f` starts returning a reference that is invalid outside of f, the problem is in `f`, not in the client of `f`

Comment: That's not what I meant. If `f` all of the sudden changes signature and returns a reference, what do you want `a` to be? A reference referring to the same object as the reference returned? Or a copy of the object? I'm saying that if your mean that `a` should be a local variable, declare it as such with `auto` or `const auto`. If you mean that `a` should refer to whatever f() returns, declare it as a reference.

Comment: Still, if the returned reference is `const`, there should be no problem in using it. And if not and it shouldn't be changed, then I guess the bad choice is still in `f`. If `f` returns a reference, it is basically saying "do whatever you want with that". And if that's indeed the case, then I don't need the copy anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If `class A` have move-constructor then just use `A a = f();`
If you know nothing about `class A` you can rely only on RVO or NRVO optimization.

Comment: Suppose I don't know anything about A; why not `A&& a = f()` or `const A& a = f()` (to make sure I don't make an additional unnecessary copy, even if *RVO does not take place)?

Comment: Also, you say "if it has a move-ctor use `A a = f()`". **Otherwise** I suppose your answer implies "use `A a = f()`" anyway. So, didn't you by chance mean `A&& a = f()`? If not, how is the knowledge of A important?

Comment: Usge of 'A&& a = f()' can lead to dangling reference.
Please, consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient

Comment: That doesn't apply since the function didn't "move" anything out. Notice the signature of f is postulated to always be `A f()`

Comment: Ok. In my answer I just want to say that it doesn't matter what option you'll use to initialize 'A'. It completely depends on move-semantic of 'class A'. So if 'A' doesn't have move-constructor then 'A' object can't be moved. It'll be copied or optimized with RVO.

Comment: Exactly, but if it happens not to be optimized with RVO, and it happens not to have a move ctor, but you use a const ref, it won't be copied and you enforce the equivalent of RVO as a programmer. So what is the downside?

Comment: If you want to avoid relying on copy/move elision, you have to dodge any copy/move semantics, and there is only one way. Declare `f` as `void f(A& ret)` and call `A a; f(a);`.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA I don't get why not relying on the elision implies having to dodge it. Sorry, I just can't understand why c) (or b), if that's the case) are better than a), being explicit and independent of compiler choices. BTW, did you see my last [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18445944/revisions)?

Comment: @ricab: Not relying on elision means having to dodge it, because the Standard permits compilers to perform copy/move elision so long as external behaviour of the program remains unchanged. Which means that copying and moving are semantic concerns, not low-level ones. You have but few control over what code will be emitted in the end. For the sake of the argument, you suppose that a given compiler does not elide copy constructors. Then let me suppose that this  compiler implements every reference as a pointer. This compiler will then incur an extra indirection on every access through your ref.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA What I meant by "not relying on copy elision" is: I don't mind if it happens, but I don't want extra copies whether it happens or not.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA: If `A` is heavy (suppose it's a container or sth), the extra pointer indirection will be negligible compared to an extra copy. Also, I guess if you use a const reference to a temporary, there is no real indirection involved

Comment: @ricab: And I guess the compiler implementing copy-elision is a reasonable expectation. Containers get moved, not copied. If A is heavy, don't you think there is another copy involved in returning your object from `f`? `f` cannot guess that its return value will be bound to a reference.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA: Yes, copy-elision is a reasonable expectation, and yes, I could still expect another copy if there was any copy at all (copy plus assignment to be precise). And yes, std containers wouldn't be a good example (e.g. some pre-C++11 custom container rather). And yes, if one guesses in one case, one can also guess in the other. I think I got it now...

Comment: There is no assignment in `A a = f();` It's called copy-initialisation (Standard 8.5.14), and it may invoke a move.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA I was thinking "With a) if the compiler generated code creating a copy, it would be a naive compiler, but a valid one nonetheless. So why not use c)?". The answer is that if the same copy happened with c), it'd be a stupid compiler, but still valid (I think it would be valid if it created 100 copies). I wouldn't be enforcing "no copy". In fact the copy ctor needs to be defined for A in order for any definition of `A f()` to be valid. Thanks a lot for the discussion. I will upvote your answer. If you add something along these lines and drop the auto stuff I will select it ;)

Comment: Actually, there is something about selection between move and copy I need to check in the Standard beforehand. I will not drop the `auto` stuff, because if `f` suddenly returns B instead of A, and B is a derivative of A, you get silent slicing with a).

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA: Right, silent slicing is an argument that makes more sense! I guess I will start using that!

Comment: @ricab That's what c) prevents, actually. If you bind the return value to `A& a` or `const A& a`, then when `a` gets destructed, it refers to an object of type `B`and the destructor of class `B` is called. But your code sees it as a reference to `A`.