# Optimal way to return local value in C++11

Tags: c++11, copy, move-semantics, return-by-reference, return-by-value

In the old days, if I wanted a string representation of an object `A`, I would write something with the signature `void to_string(const A& a, string& out)` to avoid extra copies. Is this still the best practice in C++11, with move semantics and all?

I have read several comments on other contexts that suggest relying on RVO and instead writing `string to_string(const A& a)`. But RVO is not guaranteed to happen! So, how can I, as the programmer of to_string, guarantee the string is not copied around unnecessarily (independently of the compiler)?

Comment: This hasn't been the best practice in a long time (even before moves).

Comment: If RVO can't be used then the compiler will first try moving before if defaults back to copying. Stop worrying, just write things naturally.

Comment: If you have to guarantee it, then you have to use a reference.  However, I know of no compilers which don't implement RVO.  And if such a beast does exist, it is unlikely that the performance of its generated code will matter.  Either way, just use RVO.

Comment: The complete answer would be spread out over several answers and comments, so I created a community wiki post with the self-contained answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I gathered from feedback and other resources:

The straightforward return by value is the idiom because:

- in practice copy/move elision will take place most of the time;
- the move ctor will be used on fallback;
- preventing the improbable case of a copy actually happening is not worth the less readable code
- passing the reference in requires the object to have already been created

  - not always feasible (for instance, there might be no default ctor) and which
  - one initialization too much also has to be taken into account if the issue is performance

However, if the typical usage is anticipated to be something like

```
std::string s;
while (i_need_to)
{
    to_string(get_A(), s);
    process(s);
    update(i_need_to);
}
```

and if the type in question has a default constructor*, then it may still make sense to pass the object that should hold the return by reference.

*considering string here only as an example, but the question and answers could be generalized

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the code in your function is of the form:

```
std::string data = ...;
//do some processing.
return data;
```

Then this is required to call `std::string`'s move constructor if elision is not available. So worst-case, you get to move from your internal string.

If you can't afford the cost of a move operation, then you'll have to pass it as a reference.

That being said... do you worry about compilers not being able to inline short functions? Are you concerned about whether or not small wrappers won't be properly optimized away? Does the possibility of the compiler not optimizing `for` loops and the like bother you? Do you think about whether `if(x < y)` is faster than `if(x - y < 0)`?

If not... then why do you care about copy/move elision (the technical term for "return value optimization", as it's used in more places than that)? If you are using a compiler that can't support copy elision, then you're using a horrible compiler that probably can't support a ton of other optimizations. For performance sake, you'd be better off spending your time upgrading your compiler than turning return values into references.

> preventing the improbable case of a copy actually happening is not worth the ... hassle? less readable code? what exactly? what is the extra thing that weights on the side of simple return?

The "extra thing" is that this:

```
std::string aString = to_string(a);
```

Is more readable than this:

```
std::string aString;
to_string(a, aString);
```

In the first case, it is *immediately* apparent that `to_string` is initializing a string. In the second, it isn't; you have to look up `to_string`'s signature to see that it's taking a *non-`const`* reference.

The first case is not even "idiomatic"; that's how everyone would normally write it. You would never see a `to_int(a, someInt)` call for integers; that's ridiculous. Why should integer creation and object creation be so different? You shouldn't *have to care* as a programmer whether too many copies are happening for a return value or something. You just do things the simple, obvious, and well-understood way.

Comment: +1 *"For performance sake, you'd be better off spending your time upgrading your compiler than turning return values into references."* Well said!  :)

Comment: I am not really worried with any particular performance case, nor am I using a weird compiler. Simply trying to understand, in general terms, what the idiom is and why. And I am indeed interested in the performance impact of loop unrolling or why ++i is better than i++. Of course once I settle on a reasoning I can understand I just use that and not think all the details over each time. But I do prefer to understand the whys first, hence the question

Comment: What I can understand from the answers, comments and what I read elsewhere is that the straightforward return by value is the idiom because: in practice copy/move elision will take place most of the time; the move ctor will be used on fall-back; preventing the improbable case of a copy actually happening is not worth the ... hassle? less readable code? what exactly? what is the extra thing that weights on the side of simple return? Because the code doesn't seem that less readable if you're passing a non-const ref, nor is it really much of a hassle...

Comment: @ricab: (A) If there's a move assignment operator, then there is no chance of a copy happening.  (B) Why write confusing and less readable code if you get no benefit for it?  One intuitively expects `get_name` to take nothing and return a string like object.  One does not intuitively expect `get_name` to require you to give it a string.  You may have gotten _used_ to that, but that doesn't mean it's intuitive.  It's confusing.  You just got used to it.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks, you have a point, I do get it is more readable to have the return value actually be returned. But wouldn't that be an argument against receiving non-const references at all?

Comment: @ricab: No, if the function is `update_height`, you'd expect to provide it a non-const reference, and either return nothing, or maybe some tidbit of information.

Comment: Now I am only missing the argument for the [converse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445944/which-type-to-declare-to-avoid-copy-and-make-sure-returned-value-is-moved)

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't agree with the last part of your argument: there are differences in the way you treat fundamental data types and other heavier things (e.g. receive by const ref or by value). So the assertion that you wouldn't do `to_int(a, someInt&)` doesn't imply you wouldn't do `to_Heavy(a, Heavy&)`. I also don't think "that's how everyone would normally write it" (unless you add "in java" or sth), you see it often. Arguing it is not the best is not the same as arguing it is absurd. And you have an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18454872/563765) where it would make sense

Comment: @ricab: "*there are differences in the way you treat fundamental data types and other heavier things*" No, there are differences in the way *you* treat them. There don't *have* to be. Not for performance reasons, and certainly not in the *general* case. If you want a general, default idiom, the default in C++11 is to return the object by value. That doesn't preclude exceptional circumstances, but those circumstances *by definition* are out of the ordinary.

Comment: @NicolBolas So do *you* write `f(vector<Heavy> v)` instead of `f(const vector<Heavy>& v)`? Or `f(const char *& cstr)` instead of `f(char * cstr)`?

Comment: @ricab: If I'm giving someone ownership of the array, I do (when using C++11). If I'm not, I use a `const&`, because that's how you give someone access to something without letting them claim ownership of it. Just because you can't use something as a value type in all circumstances doesn't mean you shouldn't use it as one whenever possible. The fewer rules you have, the simpler your code.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I didn't quite understand you, but so if you allow `f` to change your str, do you write `f(char * const &)` instead of `f(char *)` and claim that is simpler code?

Comment: @ricab: I don't use `char*`s, so the question is moot. And why would I pass a reference to a pointer unless I expected the user to modify the pointer?

Comment: @NiclBolas: Take T* instead of char* - pointers are part of C++ whether *you* use them or not. I am only pointing out that, despite your belief otherwise, there are differences in the way *everyone else* uses light fundamental types and composite types. Otherwise, when passing a read-only pointer (fundamental type) variable (whether the pointee was writable or not) people would use the same form as when passing say, a read-only vector: `f(T * const &)` (compare with `f(vector const &)`). And they of course don't. Just like most people write `f(int)`, not `f(const int&)`

Answer (score 4):

Back in the old days (1970-1980) you could pretty much predict the performance of an algorithm by counting floating point divides.

That is no longer true today.  However there is a similar rule you can use to estimate performance today:

> Count the number of trips to the heap:  both `new/malloc` and `delete/free`.

Given:

```
std::string
to_string(const A& a)
{
    std::string s;
    // fill it up
    return s;
}

std::string s = test();
```

I count 1 new, assuming you don't reallocate `s` internal to `to_string()`.  That one allocation is done as you put data into `s`.  I know that `std::string` has a fast (allocation-free) move constructor.  So whether or not RVO happens is not relevant to estimating the performance of `to_string()`.  There is going to be 1 allocation in creating the `s` outside of `to_string()`.

Now consider:

```
void
to_string(const A& a, string& out)
{
    out = ...
}

std::string s;
to_string(a, s);
```

As I've written it, it still consumes 1 memory allocation.  So this is about the same speed as the return-by-value version.

Now consider a new use-case:

```
while (i_need_to)
{
    std::string s = to_string(get_A());
    process(s);
    update(i_need_to);
}
```

According to our previous analysis the above is going to do 1 allocation per iteration.  Now consider this:

```
std::string s;
while (i_need_to)
{
    to_string(get_A(), s);
    process(s);
    update(i_need_to);
}
```

I know that `string` has `capacity()`, and that capacity can be recycled over many uses in the above loop.  The worst case scenario is that I still have 1 allocation per iteration.  The best case scenario is that the first iteration will create capacity that is large enough to handle all other iterations, and that the entire loop will only do 1 allocation.

The truth will likely lie somewhere in between the worst and best case scenarios.

The best API will depend upon the use cases you think your function will most likely be in.

Count allocations to estimate performance.  And then measure what you've coded up.  In the case of `std::string`, there will likely be a short string buffer that may impact your decision.  In the case of [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org), on a 64 bit platform, `std::string` will store up to 22 `char` (plus the terminating null) before it makes a trip to the heap.