# How to avoid unnecessary instances using rvalue references in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I would like to create a custom container `Container` that stores data in individual arrays. However, to facilitate easy iterations over the container, I provide a 'view' on the container by overloading `operator[]` and return a single struct `Value` that holds all container variables as references to the actual container. This is what I got so far:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Value {
  Value(int& data) : data_(data) { }
  int& data() { return data_; }
  int& data_;
};

struct Container {
  Value makeValue(int i) { return Value(data_[i]); } // EDIT 1
  Value&& operator[](int i) {
    // return std::forward<Value>(Value(data_[i]));
    return std::forward<Value>(makeValue(i)); // EDIT 1
  }

  int data_[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  // Create and output temporary
  Container c;
  cout << c[2].data() << endl; // Output: 3 - OK!

  // Create, modify and output copy
  Value v = c[2];
  cout << v.data() << endl; // Output: 3 - OK!
  v.data() = 8;
  cout << v.data() << endl; // Output: 8 - OK!

  // Create and output reference
  Value&& vv = c[2];
  cout << vv.data() << endl; // Output: 8 - OK, but weird:
                             // shouldn't this be a dangling reference?
  cout << vv.data() << endl; // Output: 468319288 - Bad, but that's expected...
}
```

The code above is working as far as I can tell, but I'm wondering if I use the best approach here:

1. Is it correct to return the `Value` as an rvalue reference if I want to avoid unnecessary copying?
2. Is the use of `std::forward` correct? Should I use `std::move` (both will work in this example) or something else?
3. The output of the compiled program is stated in the comments. Is there any way I can avoid the dangling reference when I declare `Value&& vv...` (or even forbid it syntactically)?

**EDIT 1**

I made a small change to the source code so that the `Value` instance is not directly created in the `operator[]` method but in another helper function. Would that change anything? Should I use the `makeValue(int i)` method as shown or do I need to use `std::move`/`std::forward` in here?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to return the Value as an rvalue reference if I want to avoid unnecessary copying?

No. Returning rvalue references from something that isn't a helper like `std::move` or `std::forward` is flat-out wrong. Rvalue references are still references. Returning a reference to a temporary or a local variable has always been wrong and it still is wrong. These are the same C++ rules of old.

> Is the use of `std::forward` correct? Should I use `std::move` (both will work in this example) or something else?

The answer to the previous question kinda makes this one moot.

> The output of the compiled program is stated in the comments. Is there any way I can avoid the dangling reference when I declare `Value&& vv...` (or even forbid it syntactically)?

It's not the `Value&& vv = c[2];` part that creates a dangling reference. It's `operator[]` itself: see answer to the first question.

Rvalue references change pretty much nothing in this case. Just do things as you would have always done:

```
Value operator[](int i) {
    return Value(data_[i]);
}
```

Any compiler worth using will optimise this into a direct initialisation of the return value without any copies or moves or anything. With dumb/worthless/weird/experimental compilers it will at worst involve a move (but why would anyone use such a thing for serious stuff?).

So, the line `Value v = c[2];` will initialise `v` directly. The line `Value&& vv = c[2];` will initialise a temporary and bind it to the rvalue reference variable. These have the same property as `const&` used to, and they extend the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference, so it wouldn't be dangling.

In sum, the same old C++ of always still works, and still gives results that are both correct and performant. Do not forget it.

Comment: I just made a small change to my example in the source code - do your answers still hold in this case as well?

Comment: It does not make a difference: op[] is still returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: OK, I think I understood that. In terms of avoiding unnecessary copies, is the signature/definition of `makeValue(int i)` correct like this or should I change something here?

Answer (score 3):

Returning a reference to a temporary objects, even if it is an r-value reference, is always wrong! By the time you access the object it will be gone. In that case it also doesn't do what you want it to do, anyway: if you want to avoid unnecessary copies, have one return statement returning a temporary! Copy/move elision will take care of the object not being copied:

```
Value operator[](int i) {
    return Value(data_[i]);
}
```

Passing the temporary object through a function will inhibit copy/move elision and not copying/moving is even less work than moving.

Comment: What if I do not create the instance of `Value` in the `operator[]` method but in another helper function (see `makeValue(int i)` above)?

Comment: Copy/move elision also works along a chain of return statements. Your version inhibits copy/move elision due to the call to `std::forward()` and you still return a reference to an object which is destroyed before the reference is accessed.

Comment: Does that mean that the `std::forward<Value>(makeValue(i))` in this case is necessary, or could I just write `makeValue(i)` instead?

Comment: Calling any function taking a return value and somehow returning it will introduce a move/copy. Returning the result of another function directly will [normally] result in copy/move elision, i.e., using `std::forward()` is counter-productive in this case. `std::forward()` is needed when passing arguments to functions as copy/moves cannot (in general) be elided when passing arguments on.