# Return value or rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

In Scott Meyer's new book, he proposes an example usage for rvalue reference qualifiers that looks something like this:

```
class Widget {
private:
    DataType values;

public:
    DataType& data() &  { return values; } 
    DataType  data() && { return std::move(values); } // why DataType?
};
```

So that:

```
auto values = makeWidget().data();
```

move-constructs `values` instead of copy-constructing it.

Why does the rvalue-ref-qualified `data()` return `DataType` instead of `DataType&&`? `auto` would still deduce `DataType` in that case (although `decltype(auto)` wouldn't - but that can't be the only reason to prefer to return a value instead of an ravlue ref). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1116763/2069064) highly voted answer returns an rvalue ref, which makes more sense conceptually to me.

Comment: "the highly voted answer" correctly suggests to return by value, have a read once again

Comment: @bobah It says "Your case of returning an rvalue reference would be a good idea in other occasions." before proposing `Beta_ab && getAB() && { return move(ab); }`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DataType data() && { return std::move(values); } // why DataType?

auto values = makeWidget().data();
```

The temporary that holds the return value will be initialized through the move-constructor, copy-initialized from `move(values)`.

Then that temporary initializes `values`, but since `makeWidget().data()` is an rvalue (prvalue to be precise) the move-constructor is called again - with the temporary as its argument.

Now consider [**copy-elision**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved
>   or copied into an object of the same cv-unqualified type, the
>   copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is constructed, it is
>   constructed directly in the storage where it would otherwise be moved
>   or copied to. When the nameless temporary is the argument of a return
>   statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value
>   optimization".

So the second move will (presumably) be completely elided, and only one is left - the one we would have had anyway, had the return type been the rvalue reference.

The problem with returning an rvalue reference is that if we write

```
auto&& values = makeWidget().data();
```

`values` will be dangling as binding an xvalue to a reference doesn't extend anythings lifetime. When we return the object type, the temporaries lifetime is extended.

Comment: So the only reason is because of the dangling with `auto&&`? In either case, we'd only get one move done... the one from the member `values` into the object `values` (I should've named them differently in the question).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit references are not temporaries.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The object referred to by `makeWidget()` probably is. But it doesn't matter; that's not bound to anything.

Comment: @Barry In my opinion, `auto&&` as a variable type is not the primary concern when returning rvalue refs that alias their complete object. Though this leads to issues with range-based for loops (where the `auto&&` is hidden), also consider function parameters (forwarding refs, rvalue refs and lref-to-const)

Comment: @dyp Can you provide an example for those other cases? I'm not sure I see the difference.

Comment: @Barry [Who is to blame for this range based for over a reference to temporary?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/262215) ; for function parameters, I might have been wrong, since constructing an example is not straight-forward. In any case, the temporary lives at least until the end of the full-expression, so problems only arise when defining variables in the scope of the temporary's creation, and maybe for braced-init-lists (IIRC each initializer is a full-expression).

Comment: @dyp Thank you for that. The examples you have at the end are exactly what I was looking for. Do you mind copying those over to here as an answer?

Answer (score -2):

finally get this clear by researching StackOverflow and tech blogs, here contribute back a grain of my thoughts

```cpp
    class Widget { 
        private: DataType values; 
        public: DataType& data() & { return values; } 
        // return rvalue, okay, ref-qualifier necessary, since values not usable after move
        DataType data() && { return std::move(values); }
        // return rvalue reference, okay
        DataType&& data_ref() && { return std::move(values); }
    };

    // note that auto is deduced to be Widget type
    // okay, rvalue returned by function call moves construct w1
    // if compiler implemented RVO copy elision, the move in move construct likely be elided
    auto w1 = Widget().data(); 
    // okay, rvalue reference returned by function call moves construct w2
    auto w2 = Widget().data_ref(); 

    // auto&& is a universal reference, deduced to be Widget&& rvalue reference
    // dangling reference, bad. temporary copy is destroyed, so w3 is a dangling rvalue reference to values in the destroyed copy
    auto&& w3 = Widget().data_ref();
```

Answer (score -4):

`auto&&` would be broken if it returned an rvalue reference. The linked answer is broken in this particular case.

The core problem here is that you can overload on lvalue or rvalue, but there are really three value categories you might want to know about- value, lvalue, and rvalue. C++ does not distinguish between value and rvalue when calling member functions, so you can't know if it's correct to return an rvalue reference or not. No matter which decision you make, it's easy to construct examples where it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean lvalue, xvalue, and prvalue?

Comment: you can go for "Maximum confusion" if you want, but I prefer to keep it in the realms of "Where non-language-lawyers reside".

Comment: I honestly don't know what exactly you mean by each of your value category names.  I'll stick with the terms I've seen other people (not just the Standard) use.

Comment: How is the linked answer "broken"? He immediately move-constructs a new object before anything can dangle.