# How can I extend the lifetime of an rvalue reference returned from an accessor?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Related to this question: [Return value or rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368236/return-value-or-rvalue-reference) - I found that the following example does appear to be unsafe, at least with g++ 6.1.0 and Boost 1.60.0.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct A {
    A();
    A(const A&);
    A(A&&);
    ~A();

    int* begin();
    int* end();

    int* buf;
};

boost::optional<A> f();

int test() {
    int res = 0;
    for (int n : f().value())
        res += n;
    return res;
}
```

When I look in the generated assembly code, I definitely see `A::~A()` being called before `A::begin()`, `A::end()`, etc.

The question is: What would be the least intrusive way to force a move construction before the temporary returned by `f()` goes away?

Comment: I think `A a = f().value();` should be safe as http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary says "a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a simple template function that on an rvalue, calls a move constructor, but on an lvalue just returns the same thing.

```
template <typename T>
T extend_if_rval(T&& x) {
    return std::forward<T>(x);
}
```

Then, if I change the `for` to:

```
for (int n : extend_if_rval(f().value()))
```

the generated assembly looks good: it first calls `A::A(A&&)` before `A::begin()`, `A::end()`, and eventually `A::~A()` after the end of the loop.  (Of course it can still throw an exception, but that's by the design of the example.)

Comment: `template<class T> T extend_if_rval(T&& x) { return std::forward<T>(x); }`. No need for the second overload. Maybe `static_assert(!is_rvalue_reference_v<T>)` if you want to guard against idiots.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create an explicit temporary:

```
for (int n : A(f().value())) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Sure, that works if `A` is a simple type - but what if it were something more complex that you didn't want to type?  I guess that was sort of an implicit point of my template function, to deduce the type to construct rather than having to name it.  (Also, I think the `std::move` here is unnecessary.)