# C++ Clang optimization bug with template

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

I have a simple piece of code as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename LocType, typename Base>
class MapWrapper {
public:
  Base&& get_and_erase(LocType x) {
    Base ret = std::move(_data[x]);
    _data.erase(x);
    // Uncomment the cout will give correct result
    // std::cout << "retval = " << ret << std::endl;
    return std::move(ret);
  }
  void increase(const LocType& x, const Base& w) {
    if (w == 0.0) {
      return;
    }
    _data[x] += w;
  }
private:
  std::map<LocType, Base> _data;
};

int main() {
  MapWrapper<int, double> a;
  a.increase(1, 1.0);
  double w = a.get_and_erase(1);
  std::cout << "w = " << w << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I think the output should be 1. It works fine in g++ 4.8.2, but when I use my MAC with

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

and compile it with:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -O2 debug.cpp -o debug
```

What I get is :

```
w = 2.64619e-260
```

The only way I can make it correct is to turn off `-O2` or force an output by uncomment the `std::cout` in the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient

Comment: I believe there are very few instances, where an r-valze return type isn't an error let alone necessary / an optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior. `get_and_erase` returns a reference to a local variable. Enabling optimizations exposes this bug. Your explicit `std::move` fools the warning the compiler would usually emit for returning a reference to a local variable.

To fix this, change the return type to just `Base`, and the return statement to just `return ret;`; the move is unnecessary and actually a pessimization.