# Rvalue reference behavior while returning from a function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue-reference

In the below code:

```
class Myclass
{    
public:
    Myclass() = default;
    ~Myclass() = default;

    Myclass(Myclass&&) = default;
    Myclass& operator=(Myclass&&) = default;

    Myclass(const Myclass&) = delete;    
    Myclass& operator=(const Myclass&) = delete;
};

Myclass GetObj()
{
    Myclass obj;    
    return obj;
}

Myclass WrapperOfGetObj()
{
    Myclass&& Wrapobj = GetObj();

    return Wrapobj;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When it is compiled it gives error in function `WrapperOfGetObj` on `return` `Wrapobj`. Error is

**'Myclass::Myclass(const Myclass &)': attempting to reference a deleted function**

It means it is trying to call `deleted` copy constructor. As I know `Wrapobj` is lvalue and when it being returned its behavior should be same as `obj` in `GetObj` method i.e, *calling move constructor at the time of `return`*.
**Then why it is looking for copy constructor**? What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to use `std::move()` to make an rvalue explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that (as T.C. wraps up in the comment section) `Wrapobj` is a reference, not an object, therefore implicit moving - i.e. treating the returned lvalue as an rvalue - does not apply in this case (see [[class.copy]/32](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#32)).

You could fix this by writing:

```
Myclass Wrapobj = GetObj();
```

Instead of the current:

```
Myclass&& Wrapobj = GetObj();
```

Or by explicitly `std::move()`ing `Wrapobj` when returning it. I'd personally advise to go for the first option.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient) might be good extra reading for this topic.

Comment: The expression `Wrapobj` is an lvalue of type `MyClass`; expressions never have reference type (after the [expr]/5 adjustment). The problem is that the implicit move only applies to objects of automatic storage duration ([class.copy]/32), and a reference is not an object. Moreover, "named lvalues in a return statement won't be treated as rvalues by the compiler if their type is different from the return type of the function" is incorrect since [CWG 1579](http://wg21.link/CWG1579).

Comment: @T.C.: Has that been clarified in the Standard? Back in the day when I was more active I used to be convinced of that, but then I figured it was probably up to interpretation (see [Scott's blog post](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.cz/2015/02/expressions-can-have-reference-type.html)). Is there a final word? Anyway I'll try to reword it more precisely.

Comment: I don't think it's very useful to consider the pre-adjustment type when it vanishes instantly (hence the parenthesized qualifier).

Comment: @T.C.: Re that CWG issue, the current wording of [class.copy]/32 says "When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met [...] and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, [...]", and the criteria for elision ([class.copy]/31, first bullet) specify that the type has to be the same (ignoring cv-qualifiers) in order for elision to be possible.

Comment: ... "or when the expression in a `return` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function [...]". It's `(copy elision criteria met && lvalue) || (id-expression designating an automatic object)` This sentence is a tricky parse, I know...

Comment: @T.C.: Yeah, you're right, I guess I parsed it the wrong way. However, I'm confused. Why is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UuvVd79Q87eaz6PQ) illegal then? Both Clang and GCC reject it

Comment: @AndyProwl did you get answer why you program gets same error... I am confused. can you say few word on that.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj I'm trying to figure that out. I asked another question on Stack Overflow. Anyway the solution/workaround I would suggest you for the moment is to `return std::move(Wrapobj)`.

Comment: @T.C.: I wrote a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039379/why-is-move-constructor-not-picked-when-returning-a-local-object-of-type-derived?noredirect=1#comment67358107_40039379)

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks for the answer. Edited. Sorry it took me a while to figure it all out.

Comment: @AndyProwl one question if in WrapperOfGetObj() function - I do WrapObj.SomeMeberVariable = assignSomeValue.
Is that fine? as WrapObj is an xvalue.