# Why is move constructor not picked when returning a local object of type derived from the function's return type?

Tags: c++, return, language-lawyer, move-semantics, compiler-bug

The following code is rejected by both [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UuvVd79Q87eaz6PQ) and [GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/U1k6P5mdJpX9vkGa) (trunk versions):

```
#include <memory>

struct Base 
{
    Base() = default; 
    Base(Base const&) = delete;
    Base(Base&&) = default;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived() = default; 
    Derived(Derived const&) = delete;
    Derived(Derived&&) = default;
};    

auto foo()
    -> Base
{
    Derived d;    
    return d;   // ERROR HERE
}
```

Causing the following error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'Base foo()': prog.cc:21:12: error: use of deleted function 'Base::Base(const Base&)'
     return d;
            ^
```

According to [class.copy]/32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an exception-declaration, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **or when the expression in a return statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration** declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, **overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue**

If the sentence above is meant to be parsed as `(copy elision criteria met && lvalue) || (id-expression designating an automatic object)`, as [this CWG defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579) seems to indicate, why isn't the last condition applying here? Is there a compiler bug both in Clang and GCC?

On the other hand, if the sentence is meant to be parsed as `(copy elision criteria met && (lvalue || id-expression designating an automatic object))`, isn't this a very misleading wording worth a DR?

Comment: Doesn't your return statement correspond to `return Base{d}`? And so should be forbidden by design? At least that's what I would naively expecting without a deep-dive into the C++ standard.

Comment: @davidhigh: Slicing is not forbidden by the language, although there are not many use cases for it. For instance, you can do `Derived d; Base b = std::move(d);`. The point here is whether `d` should be treated as an rvalue (i.e. as if I had written `return std::move(d)`) or not.

Comment: thanks, further question: Where should copy elision set in? Naively, it should correspond to a `std::move(Base{d})`, not a `Base{std::move(d)}`. Or?

Comment: The next line after the ones you quoted, says *"__If
the first overload resolution fails or was not performed__, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected
constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), __overload resolution is
performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.__".* Could this be the case here?

Comment: @davidhigh: Copy elision is not viable here. The conditions in [class.copy]/31 rule it out pretty clearly (different type than the return type). However, the way I parse that sentence in [class.copy]/32, should make the "or when" part applicable.

Comment: @davidhigh it wouldn't; [class.copy]/31 doesn't apply, because the types differ, but [class.copy]/32 and CWG DR 1579 say that it should treat `d` as an rvalue, so move-construct the actual return value, instead of copy-constructing as it does.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Well, yes, that's what's going on, but I don't see why would the first overload resolution fail or not be performed, given that quote.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall But wait there's more! When you explicitly turn `d` into an rvalue with `std::move`, the code compiles!

Comment: copy-elision was the wrong word in my question. But again, what's called, `std::move(Base{d})` or `Base{std::move(d)}`? And again, I'd expect the first. (And I'm asking although I know my *expectations* are not helpful here :-)

Comment: @davidhigh: It should be `Base{std::move(d)}`.

Comment: @davidhigh: That looks related indeed, however the final edit to the question leaves me puzzled. If that behavior was implemented in GCC 5, why is it absent in GCC 7?

Comment: @AndyProwl Doesn't seem to be properly implemented in GCC 5 either.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17483612/2412846). And based on this a [similar problem without inheritance](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/R5OofSyrpwPFfX4k). (Corrected link).

Comment: "if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified)". The selected constructor takes `Base&&`, not `Derived&&`, so the results from the first overload resolution is discarded.

Comment: @t.c. no implicit slice on implicit move, basically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[class.copy]/32 continues:

> [...] if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor
>   is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly
>   cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the
>   object as an lvalue.

The first overload resolution, treating `d` as an rvalue, selects `Base::Base(Base&&)`. The type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is, however, not `Derived&&` but `Base&&`, so the result of that overload resolution is discarded and you perform overload resolution again, treating `d` as an lvalue. That second overload resolution selects the deleted copy constructor.

Comment: Oh. How did I miss this? Anyway, this rule is an absolute, abhorrent abomination.

Comment: Life is better having error messages - "main.cpp: In function 'Base foo()':
main.cpp:21:12: error: use of deleted function 'Base::Base(const Base&)'
     return d;   // ERROR HERE
            ^
main.cpp:6:5: note: declared here
     Base(Base const&) = delete;
     ^~~~

Comment: Does anyone know the origins of the rule, or do we have to call Richard Smith to explain? :D

Comment: The origin is some core issue IIRC. Regardless, the resolution of the linked core issue is therefore incomplete, since part of it was meant to support the shown code. I'll file another one once I get back.

Comment: You're answer seems to imply that [this scenario](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/R5OofSyrpwPFfX4k) -- where you got a constructor taking the rvalue-reference of the correct type -- is working. But it isn't.

Comment: @davidhigh Deleting a copy-constructor causes default-constructor and move-constructor to not be generated implicitly. See [this fixed version of your example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tzs5uuuafCrnbEns).

Comment: @Columbo This wording was in as early as N2118; don't think it's a core issue.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Sure. Dumb. Thanks. :-)

Comment: This rule reads as "implicit move does not cause implicit slicing" to me.  Extracting the state of only the base class of an object and moving it somewhere else prior to destruction does seem questionable.  In general, copy or move ctor or assign *with an implicit slice* is highly questionable.  I would be cautious.