# Why does an object returned by value have the same address as the object inside the method?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> foo() {
 int i;
 std::vector<int> a(100);
 printf("%p, %p, %p\n", &i, &a, &(a[0]));
 return a;
}

int main() {
 int i;
 std::vector<int> b = foo();
 printf("%p, %p, %p\n", &i, &b, &(b[0]));
}
```

Why do `a` and `b` have the same address for the above? Is this some kind of "cross-stack-frame" optimization? The result is the same even when I use the `-O0` option.

The output:

```
$ vim main.cpp 
$ cc -std=c++11 -lc++ main.cpp
$ ./a.out
0x7ffee28d28ac, 0x7ffee28d28f0, 0x7ff401402c00
0x7ffee28d290c, 0x7ffee28d28f0, 0x7ff401402c00
$
```

Comment: Try it on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Is this also the case when `b` is declared on the heap (i.e., outside `main`)?

Answer (score 57):

This is because of copy elision/named return value optimization (NRVO). `foo` returns a named object `a`. So the compiler is not creating a local object and returning a copy of it but creates the object at the place where the caller puts it. You can read more about it on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision. While RVO is mandatory since C++17, NRVO is not, but it looks like your compiler supports it even in case of `-O0`.

Comment: @willzeng NRVO may be optional but it has been universally implemented since early 1990s. Some compilers do provide a way to disable it, for gcc it is "-fno-elide-constructors"

Comment: @Cubbi It's not a question of whether it's implemented. If it's not mandatory, then you can't *rely* on the addresses being the same.

Comment: Since you are not using `b` in any other way compiler might have seent it appropriate to inline call to `foo()`

Answer (score 15):

Note that even without copy elision (mandatory or not), it's already possible for the addresses of the two objects to be the same because their lifetimes are non-overlapping.

Answer (score 8):

as the others have explained this is because of copy elison. You can disable that with g++ by:

```
g++ -fno-elide-constructors main.cpp
```

where `main.cpp` contains your code.

now `a` and `b` have different addresses but `a[0]` and `b[0]` will have the same
address  because of the move semantics.