# constructors not used for initialization with a temporary variable

Tags: c++, constructor

In a struct, I defined the default, move and copy constructors. However, when I tried to instantiate the object form another temporary object of the same type, none of those constructors are called. I tried removing the move constructor but still no constructors are called. Could anybody help me with this. Thank you so much.

```
struct S{
    S(){
        cout << "default" << endl;
    }
    S(S&&){
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }
    S(const S&){
        cout << "cpy" << endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    S s{S()}; 
}
```

the output is only

```
default
```

which shows only the default constructor is called for instantiating the temporary object

------------------------------------edit----------------------------------

thanks for the answers.
looks like copy elision would lead to some unexpected behaviors
I modified the code a little bit

```
struct S{
    S(){
        cout << "default" << endl;
    }
    S(S&& other){
        cout << "move" << endl;
        this->x = other.x + 100; //increase x
    }
    S(const S& other){
        cout << "cpy" << endl;
        this->x = other.x + 200; //increase x
    }
    
    int x = 10;
};
int main() {
    S s{S()};
    cout << s.x << endl;
}
```

surprisingly, s.x now is still 10.
In my opinion, move constructor should be called and therefore s.x should be incremented by 100. Am I wrong or is the compiler's optimization wrong?

Comment: *Could anybody help me with this.* -- The compiler's optimizer is smart and said "you don't need all of these copies to happen".  Now if you wrote code depending on if and when temporaries are created, then rethink what you're doing.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: That's copy elision with also other surprising effects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61792261/1023911

Comment: The code you have now is an example of one of the nastiest bugs that can exist, and that is having a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator not actually making copies.  This was bad code even in the C++ 98 days.

Comment: Basically, the copy-assignment functions do one thing, and that is to make copies.  You don't know when, where, or if they will be called by you explicitly, or the compiler implicitly, thus you must write the code with this in mind.  Can you imagine putting `S` into a `std::vector<S>` and having all sorts of different things going on every time vector makes a copy of `S`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before c++17, your code does in fact call the move-constructor. In practice, unless otherwise specified, compilers will optimize the move out of the code. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/RjRjet)

From c++17, the [wording](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) changed, and now there is mandatory copy-elision. There is no longer any temporary created, so there's nothing to move from. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XReW5d)