# why is A constructor called once?

Tags: c++

I have the following Code

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T e_;
    A(T e) : e_(e)
    {
        std::cout<<"A\n";
    }
    A(const A& other)
    {
        std::cout<<" ACopy\n";
    }
    ~A() { std::cout<<"~A\n";}
};
struct B
{
    B() { std::cout<< "B\n";}
};
int main()
{
    A a(A(A(B{})));
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why A is being constructed only once.
here is a godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/fsvzTf

Comment: See [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). The 2 temporaries are elided.

Comment: In layman's terms, the compiler is smart, saw all of that excess fat, and decided to trim it down.  It is allowed to do that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And from c++17, which is what the OP is using, the compiler is *required* to do that in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of copy elision. You can read more about it on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision.

BTW, this leads to other surprising effects as in [Why does an object returned by value have the same address as the object inside the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61792200/1023911).