# why is temporary object's address same with object's address which has the temporary object in C++

Tags: c++, copy-elision

I read some book about C++ , and I can't understand some points in here.
temporary object is born cause returning of function and this temporary object will be stored at some object. , so I have tried many time code in below

so result of this like this

```
New: 00CFFB60
Copy: 00CFFA60
T: 00CFFA60
Copy: 00CFFB54
Destroy: 00CFFA60
temp: 00CFFB54
Destroy: 00CFFB54
Destroy: 00CFFB60
```

In here , I understand "Copy object: 0115FE80" is printed because testfuction is returning T,
so In my thought , temporary object will arise and calls copy constructor with T , so address of temporary object is 00CFFB54(From **Copy: 00CFFB54**).And In this code

I just entered this temporary object to temp

I think copy elision is happened once here , am I right?

anyway , after putting this temporary object to temp , this temp has same address with temporary object from testfunction, in result **temp: 00CFFB54** so it is perfectly same with prior one **Copy: 00CFFB54**

I can't understand how these two object have same address. In my thought, these two are not same object so never have same address, I tried so many times but always these two have same address.
what is happening here ?

Comment: I think as well this is due to copy elision. With the knowledge that the function returns something (which stops to exist shortly after function return) the local `T` in `testfunction()` is constructed into the "return storage". The "return storage" in turn is the storage of `temp`. This is actually the principle of copy elision to handle situations where one objects dies directly after the assignment to another (just constructed) which is optimized by storing them effectively in the same storage (to prevent an unnecessary copy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does an object returned by value have the same address as the object inside the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792200/why-does-an-object-returned-by-value-have-the-same-address-as-the-object-inside)

Comment: Note that in addition to all the valid remarks about copy elision, the C++ Standard says very little about the address of temporaries. An optimizer may find memory available in locations that will later be used for other purposes such as holding non-temporary objects. This behavior is entirely common on the stack, but it seems equally legal to borrow heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyObject` prints out the address of the **destination** of the copy, not the source. The address displayed for the `temp = testfunction(a);` (to construct `temp` from the value returned from `testfunction`) will be of `temp`.

You could display both addresses in the copy constructor to see the difference.